# How to update a post using form wizard in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have created a multipage form using the form wizard from the form tools package and it works. I am trying to create and update view so that I can be able to update the created post.

I have tried using generic update view, this only display the page without the form. Then, I tried using the same code for the create view by using a get method but this seems not to work also.

I will appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

views.url

```
class FormWizardView(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "new_rental.html"
    form_list = [NewRentalPropertyForm, NewContractForm]
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images'))

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        rentalproperty_instance = RentalProperty()
        contract_instance = Contract()
        for form in form_list:
            rentalproperty_instance = construct_instance(form, rentalproperty_instance)
            contract_instance = construct_instance(form, contract_instance)
            rentalproperty_instance.save()
            contract_instance.rentalproperty = rentalproperty_instance
            contract_instance.save()
        return redirect('mini_rental:property_list')

class UpdateWizardView(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "update.html"
    form_list = [NewRentalPropertyForm, NewContractForm]
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images'))

    def done(self,pk, form_list, **kwargs):
        rentalproperty_instance = RentalProperty.objects.get(pk=pk)
        contract_instance = Contract()
        for form in form_list:
            rentalproperty_instance = construct_instance(form, rentalproperty_instance)
            contract_instance = construct_instance(form, contract_instance)
            rentalproperty_instance.save()
            contract_instance.rentalproperty = rentalproperty_instance
            contract_instance.save()
        return redirect('mini_rental:property_list')
```

form. html

#### Update rental listing

```
    {% load i18n %}
    <p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <table>
  {{ wizard.management_form }}
  {% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
      {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    {{ wizard.form }}
  {% endif %}
  </table>
  {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
  <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "first step" %}</button>
  <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
  {% endif %}
  <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'submit' %}"/>
</form>
{% endblock body %}
```

urls.py

```
path('property_update/<int:pk>', UpdateWizardView.as_view(forms),  name='property_update'),
path('new_rental/', FormWizardView.as_view(forms), name='new_rental'),
```